# How to enable a wordpress plugin only on blog posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, blogs

I would like to enable a wordpress plugin (this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/chp-ads-block-detector/) only on my blog posts (and not on the whole site), can you help me please?

I have tried with adding a plugin to manage plugins as WP manager etc, but they allow to disable it only on pages and posts so the plugin still appears on woocommerce product pages.

At this time I don't want to create a subdomain for blog posts.

Is there a code that I can add to function.php? Or something else to do please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/freesoul-deactivate-plugins/) for disabling another plugin in certain conditions, in your case you can set the plugin to disable the https://wordpress.org/plugins/chp-ads-block-detector/ plugin everywhere except on blog posts